# javassist can't set the super class for a class which implements a generic interface

Tags: generics, interface, javassist

javassist can't  set the superclass for a class which implements a generic interface

the code like :

```
public interface A<T>{
   T a();
}
public class Base {
  //....
}
public class B extends Base implements A<String> {
 //...
}


public class C extends Base {

}
```

the javassist code like this:

```
CtClass c = pool.getCtClass("com.test.B");
if (c.isFrozen()) {
    c.defrost();
} 
if (c.getSuperclass().getName().equals("com.test.Base")) {
    c.setSuperclass(pool.getCtClass("com.test.C"));
}
```

I want to set the class C as the superclass for class B by javassist,but it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post some code demonstrating what you'd like to do.  What is not working?

Comment: thanks，as above，I want to replace B's superclass class Base with class C, but it didn't work. there is not any wrong happen when run javassist code.

Answer (score 0):

```
cc.setGenericSignature(genericSignature);
final CtClass baseStateClass = pool.get(baseClass.getName());
cc.setSuperclass(baseStateClass);
```

it works